# How to find out about activity on comments?

Tags: support, comments

I made a simple [comment](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28146/what-are-the-rates-of-mass-shootings-in-various-developed-countries#comment106710_28149) earlier on a skeptics.SE post, and after a few hours figured that it was not an interesting line of inquiry since I got no message about activity around it. Returning to the question to check for updates I was surprised to find that it had a full 30 upvotes and replies. **Is there a convenient way to find out whether there was any activity on my comments** without having to make "cold calls" to questions I might have commented on?

Comment: By the way, at least one of the comments in that list should have shown up in your inbox as it was directed at you using the @ ping. If that never showed up, that could be an issue.

Answer (score 7):

If you go to your User page, there's a "responses" tab (under "activity"). Here you can see all of the comment responses you have gotten.

[image: My responses tab]

As you can see in the example, this can even pick up comments that weren't @ directed at you, assuming that the OP responds and there's no one else in the comment thread.. It won't tell you about upvotes, though.

As far as upvotes go... You can use the SE Data Explorer there are several [Data Queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/skeptics/query/155827/find-all-comments-ordered-by-votes?UserId=13893) for this and it works pretty well but the data isn't updated very often; only once per week, on Sundays per the comment below. Unfortunately, that means the comment you're asking about doesn't actually show up yet. So, this is a good option for older comments but it definitely has some lag.

[image: MSE Comment List]

Remember that any of these options generally are on a per-site basis, so if you're a member of multiple sites, you may have to still check several pages. Using the Data Query, though, makes it easy to switch between sites.

Comment: As to your SE Data Explorer approach, that doesn't seem too feasible since there is even more chaching than you might imagine, it's updated once a *week* only (usually sunday morning).

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to do it. Most close possibilities I find:

- favourite it; then you'll get the question in your activity tab highlighted once something happens to it.
- maybe a bit spendy to just track the activity, but considering a question is more than two days old, you can start a bounty on it. This way you'll receive direct notifications for all the comments of that question and all the answers. Comments to the answers still won't be reflected in your inbox.

Answer (score 0):

Ususlly, the comments will be pinged to me and I get notified of it by looking at my inbox, next to Stack Exchange button in the top left corner.

And of course, you can check the `Responses` tab for responses for that specific site of course. If you want to know how many votes the question has, you need to visit the question yourself.

Comment: Only @l0b0 responses ever showed up in the inbox.